# Removing the class "in" in the bootstrap accordian dynamically when clicked on the button

Tags: angular, bootstrapping

When clicked on the button the class "in" in div element must be removed dynamically.

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign a boolean value inside **app.component.ts** and when the button is clicked change the value between true or false

```
<button (click)="isVisible = !isVisible">Toggle</button>
```

and then in the div add the following

```
<div id="demo" [ngClass]="{'in': isVisible}" class="collapse">
```